# pandas dataframe replace NaN with 0 when column name in a certain date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like that:

```
time A      time B      2017-11  2017-12  2018-01  2018-02          
2017-01-24  2020-01-01  NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2016-11-28  2020-01-01  NaN      4.0      2.0      2.0
2017-03-18  2017-12-21  NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I want replace all NaN to 0 when the column name between time A and time B. for example, for third row, the time range is from 2017-03-18 to 2017-12-21, so data at the third row with columns name between this range, if it is NaN, replace it with 0, otherwise remain as the same. Hopes its clear. Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your post to replace the image with a sample of your data

Comment: And your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, not the best solution, however it works.

Here's my test sample:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([
    {"time A": "2017-01-24", "time B": np.nan,       "2016-11": np.nan, "2016-12": np.nan, "2017-01": np.nan, "2017-02": np.nan},
    {"time A": "2016-11-28", "time B": np.nan,       "2016-11": np.nan, "2016-12": 4,      "2017-01": 2,      "2017-02": 2},
    {"time A": "2016-12-18", "time B": "2017-01-01", "2016-11": np.nan, "2016-12": np.nan, "2017-01": np.nan, "2017-02": np.nan},
])

d["time B"].fillna("2020-01-01", inplace=True)
d.set_index(["time A", "time B"], inplace=True)
```

**Initial table**:

```
time A      time B      2016-11  2016-12  2017-01  2017-02          
2017-01-24  2020-01-01  NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2016-11-28  2020-01-01  NaN      4.0      2.0      2.0
2016-12-18  2017-01-01  NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Looks like `time A` is open date and `time B` is close date, or smth like that. Thus for convenience I've filled missing `time B` with any future date, for example `'2020-01-01'`

I don't like working with pivot tables, so I've used [df.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to stack it and formatted date columns:

```
d_stack = d.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
d_stack.columns = ["time A", "time B", "month", "value"]

for col in ["time A", "time B"]:
    d_stack[col] = pd.to_datetime(d_stack[col], format="%Y-%m-%d", errors="ignore")

d_stack["month"] = pd.to_datetime(d_stack["month"], format="%Y-%m", errors="ignore")
```

Now it's more convenient to fill missing values

```
def fill_existing(x):
    if (x["time A"] <= x["month"] <= x["time B"] and
            np.isnan(x["value"])):
        return 0
    else:
        return x["value"]

d_stack["value"] = d_stack.apply(fill_existing, axis=1)
```

**Output**:

```
    time A      time B      month       value
0   2017-01-24  2020-01-01  2016-11-01  NaN
1   2017-01-24  2020-01-01  2016-12-01  NaN
2   2017-01-24  2020-01-01  2017-01-01  NaN
3   2017-01-24  2020-01-01  2017-02-01  0.0
```

Finally, format `month` back and [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to return to the initial table format:

```
d_stack["month"] = d_stack["month"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m"))
pd.pivot_table(d_stack, columns="month", index=["time A", "time B"],
               values="value", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

**Result**:

```
time A      time B      2016-12  2017-01  2017-02
2016-11-28  2020-01-01  4.0      2.0      2.0
2016-12-18  2017-01-01  NaN      0.0      NaN
2017-01-24  2020-01-01  NaN      NaN      0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
newdf=df[(df.date>some_date) & (df.date<somedate)]
newdf.fillna(0)
```

newdf is the dataframe you are looking for.